# Programs or markup viewers for legal or logical content?

Tags: info-visualisation, natural-language, legal

I am interested in user interfaces that represent legal argumentation and/or logical reasoning. For professionals dealing with complex reasoning and argumentation that is mainly language-based, what tools are they using to formalize, manage and archive their documents?

I am most interested in browser-based, e.g. viewers of XML-based representations, but stand-alone applications would be fascinating too. The types of markup languages that I'm interested in seeing viewers of include: [Legal XML](http://www.legalxml.org/), [RuleML](http://ruleml.org/), and some instances of OWL and RDF.

What is out there?

Comment: Are you making the assumption that the legal arguments are a synonym for logical arguments? ;) On a more serious note, are you asking about more mind-mapping type concepts, or things like ways to read court opinions or rules and other formally structured legal documents (or something else entirely?)

Comment: Do you know of any examples yourself? That will help us understand what you mean. Can you post links or examples of any of the XML-based representations?

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney I just tried to post one example I have found so far, but I wasn't allowed to post the screenshot as a new user. I'll update the question with a bit more info as my research unfolds.

Comment: @DA01 i'm interested in any of the categories you mentioned, but unlike a mind-mapping tool or formal ontology (which describe static concepts and their relations), I'm *more* interested in formally-structured documents that include rules, arguments, proofs, inferences, etc. I know it's a tall order, but hey, that's what this site is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a system called [DR-Prolog](http://fraoula.csd.uoc.gr:6570/drprolog/index.jsp?v=main) that does logical proofs using a custom XML format for representing content. The visualization uses straight-forward box and arrow diagrams. The type of logic that it was designed for is called Defeasible reasoning.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the article '[Visualizing a Logic of Dependability Arguments](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-274/paper8.pdf)' which deals with the topic of the question. Other articles from [the conference](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-274/) may be of interest as well.